# how do make waiting for ajax to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I newbie.
I have a function application for employment (apply-job).What I do is submit the request with an ordinary link, with a click-function applied on it but processing time is quite long. I want disable "#apply-job" avoid click too much or disable window and fade for ajax to complete. Thank.
My JS:

```
$("#apply-job").click(function() {
        if($('#jobcandidate-name').val() != '' && $('#jobcandidate-email').val() != '' && $('#jobcandidate-phone').val().length >= 10 && $('#jobcandidate-address').val() != '' &&  ($("input[name='CandidateAttachment[2][fileAttachment][path]']").val() != undefined || $('#jobcandidate-curriculum_vitae').val() != '') ){
            let data = $('#apply-job-form').serialize();
            let roleArticle = $('.show_new_role :input').serialize();
            if ($('#apply-job-form').find('.has-error').length){
                swal("Thử lại", "Vui lòng kiểm tra lại thông tin!", "error");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '$urlRequest',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data : data + '&' + roleArticle
                }).done(function(result) {
                    response = JSON.parse(result);
                    if (response.type == "success"){
                        let checkReload = swal("Thành công", "Cảm ơn bạn đã ứng tuyển!", "success");
                        checkReload.then(function() {
                            location.reload();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if ($("input[name='CandidateAttachment[2][fileAttachment][path]']").val() == undefined && $('#jobcandidate-curriculum_vitae').val() == '') {
                $('#jobcandidate-curriculum_vitae').parents('.form-group').find('.txt-lable').css('color','red');
                $('#jobcandidate-curriculum_vitae').parents('.form-group').find('.show_error2').text('* Không được bỏ trống');
            }
            swal("Thử lại", "Vui lòng kiểm tra lại thông tin!", "error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Set a variable at a higher scope above `$('.apply-job')`, like `let clicked = false;` then inside `.click(function(){ clicked = true;` then inside `.done(function(result){` at the bottom  `clicked = false;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajax` has `await` option. You can use it to make the execution wait till the `ajax` all is done. Make sure you combine it with `async` which will tell there's an asynchronous step in the function. See below snippet

```
$("#apply-job").click(async function() {
  ......
  await $.ajax({
  ......
});
```

Update: to make sure the click is disabled while ajax is working, add a `disabled` attribute and assign the click only when the attribute is not present. Clear the attribute once process is complete.

```
$("#apply-job:not([disabled])").click(async function() {
  $("#apply-job").attr("disabled","disabled")
  ......
  await $.ajax({
  ......
  $("#apply-job").remoeAttr("disabled")
});
```

Comment: but I want disable  "#apply-job" avoid click too much or disable window and fade for ajax to complete